# Install vuetify material dashboard

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, dashboard

i want to use the material dashboard on vuetify themes website: [vuetify themes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/resources/themes/)

i've tried install on a new machine from zero and simply doesnt works!

Steps to reproduce:
install node.js and git...
download from: [creative tim](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vuetify-material-dashboard)
uncompress and open terminal type in: npm install...
npm run dev and in the 64~65% starts the problems

[cmd from windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRhf6.png)

hope anyone can help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the version of your project dependencies i suspect it could be the issue with your version of `eslint`

try updating your version eslint dependencies in your `package.json` and re-run `npm install`:

```
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.8",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.20.0",
```

[eslint-plugin-vue #349](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/349)